# How can I remove a question with accepted answer or withdraw my ownership to that question?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, post-disassociation

My motive behind this might seem unclear, so I'll try to explain myself. I've asked questions in Stackoverflow community in the past three years that now after a while seem very 'dumb' to myself. I like to think that I've progressed more than someone is expected to do in this time. Now in the process of finding a job I have this concern that the person evaluating me might have a look at my profile here and see those 'dumb' questions which really don't represent me today. So to sum it up: I'm insecure! But I suspect that it could be a concern to many like me.

Now is there a way to remove a question with up votes/accepted answer? or even better is it possible to just withdraw my ownership to that question so it's content can remain available to the community?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Now in the process of finding a job I have this concern that the person evaluating me might have a look at my profile here and see those 'dumb' questions which really don't represent me today

We don't come into the workplace fully formed, knowing everything there is to know.

And any hiring manager will know that - people have to learn somewhere. Having a record of that journey is not something to be insecure about/ashamed of.

In fact, this is something that is a positive - you didn't know something and instead of staying in a state of ignorance, you put yourself out there and *asked*. Which is more than a lot of people do.

Now, there are ways to disassociate a user from their question / answer, but the process is manual and therefore it needs to be a very good reason and should not be asked for a large number of posts (there is also a reputation implication for your account - any reputation gained from such disassociated posts will be gone).

I hope you reconsider this idea and choose to leave your posts as yours.

Comment: You have a great perspective on this matter. Thanks for sharing it with me!

Comment: I can tell you that I've been a programming professionally for ~18 years now, and I am still learning! Don't reject your past ;)

Comment: `but the process is manual and therefore it needs to be a very good reason and should not be asked for a large number of posts` Naughty naughty, the license doesn't state anything about having a "good reason!" Of course, it doesn't state anything about the time it takes to process the request, so...

Comment: @Won't - the answer Shog gave for requests for mass disassociation is that we can always delete the user ;)